# Loading raster results in wrong spatial location

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have read all sorts of entries about CRS inconsistencies of different layers but it just didnt help to solve my problem.

So far I have always used ArcGIS and recently changed to QGIS. My data consists of a DEM (find attached: 'rangsdorf.ovr') and several sounding points (find one example attached: 'Layer1_Verlust_mit_Maechtigkeit.shp'). All those layers have the same coordinate system (UTM) and looking at the data in ArcGIS everything is visualised the way I want it to be - the points are located within the DEM.

However, loading it into QGIS, the raster is located somewhere completly different - I really dont get it. As I said, it should all have the same coordinate reference system, and anyway I am using OTF so I´m absolutly clueless.

Link to the data: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/31xyddr78qklsnf/AAA68tY06D-B4TISvaMX602Aa?dl=0

Comment: in ArcGIS if you save as a tiff (geotiff) with the world file you should be able to load the raster in QGIS without the issue (.ovr does seem to have the projection info with it)

Comment: Where is the data supposed to be located? UTM zone33 in the Shapefile seems to make no sense.

Comment: Ovr is the overview file. I suppose you have somewhere also another file that is the real DEM in native resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filename extension .ovr stands for overviews which are often called as pyramid layers. Ovr file holds the subsampled versions of the original image, typically with 2, 4, 8, 16, 32.... times bigger pixel size than the original. See this ESRI document http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000026000000 and this GDAL one http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html. Ovr file is actually a tiled tiff file but it is not meant to be used directly. You should find the real DEM file, perhaps 'rangsdorf.tif', place it into the same directory where you have now the .ovr file and open the tiff with QGIS.